# High ping to router when running a game

Tags: networking, wireless, hardware

I have tried to play rocket league on ubuntu to the lag is unbearable. I am connected on wifi. `lspci | grep -i network` tells me i have a `Ralink corp. RT3062 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R`

I have noticed something strange: when pinging my router i get an average of 3-4ms, however once i am playing the game my ping jumps into the hundreds.

Are there any settings i can fiddle with to try and make this smoother?

Edit: streaming netflix etc does not affect the ping times to my router like playing a game

Comment: Try `ping askubuntu.com`, that's certainly gonna be higher than 3-4ms, and maybe more similar to the ping you get in-game

Comment: @M.Becerra about 10-15ms out of game. same high ping while in a game

Comment: also lots of packet loss while in game

Comment: Try pinging the server you're connecting to in Rocket League, rather than some other arbitrary server. Or are you saying latency increases when trying to talk to other sites while RL is running?

Comment: @dobey even just pinging my router!